# Proving DeMorgan's laws, basic case with 2 sets (From Casella and Berger) (Typo in solution?)

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Required to prove the following:

$$(A \cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c$$

The textbook's solution:

[Casella and Berger Ex 1.3c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qi7z.png)

Isn't the first iff statement incorrect?

$$ x \in (A \cup B)^c \iff x \notin A \text{ or } x \notin B $$

I am under the impression that the second statement implies x can be in A or B (as x is not in A *or* x is not in B)

If this is indeed a typo, what would a proof look like? I'm struggling with this.

Comment: yes it is incorrect. it should be $x\in(A\cup B)^c\leftrightarrow x\notin A\text{ and } x\notin B$

Comment: Is that a proof though? Wouldn't there be an intermediate step, given that it just seems that you've wrote the LHS and RHS of the expression in terms of sets and said they both imply each other?

Comment: yes the proof is just applying DeMorgan for propositional logic. Another step could be added $x\in (A\cup B)^C \leftrightarrow \neg(x\in A \vee x\in B)\leftrightarrow \neg(x\in A) \wedge \neg(x\in B)$

Answer (score 0):

the only typo is that **or** it should be an **and** istead :
$$
x \in (A \cup B)^c \iff x \notin A \text{ and } x \notin B
$$

Comment: As I said to the other comment, is that a proof though? Wouldn't there be an intermediate step, given that it just seems that you've wrote the LHS and RHS of the expression in terms of sets and said they both imply each other?